# How to get cookie value for different session in same browser?

Tags: javascript

Am storing session time out value in cookie named "sesionTimeOut"

I am opening different web page (two tabs in same browser)that has different time out values .Session will be destroyed based on the cookie time out value.In this case how do I get two different kind of cookie values for these two session.

Am getting the cookie value which is currently updated for both the session.I want time out cookie for each session

Comment: a) cookies are not per tab, they are per URL path and shared by all tabs and windows in the same brower  b) why not manage session timeout on the server? Seems safer, too (people cannot extend their session by playing with the cookies).

Comment: What if your users have cookies disabled?
Doing what you suggest above isn't going to work. Cookies are shared accross tabs...